# Zero-Length regexes and infinite matches?

Tags: regex

In trying to elaborate an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34240738/1219280) question, I am now trying to come to terms with the behavior/meaning of Zero-Length regular expressions.

I often use www.regexr.com as a playground to test/debug/understand what's going on in regular expressions.

So we have this most banal scenario:

The regex is `a*`

The input string is `dgwawa`
(As a matter of fact, the string here is irrelevant)

Why this behavior of reporting that this regex will match infinitely, since it matches zero occurrences of the preceding character ?

Why can't the result be 6 matches, one for each character position (since at every character, regardless of whether it is an a or not, there is a match, since zero matches is a match)?

How does it get into matching infinitely ? So it does not *check/progress* a character at a time?

I wonder how/where does it get itself into an infinite loop.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You selected JavaScript regex flavor at regexr.com online regex tester. JavaScript regex engine does not move the index automatically when a pattern that can match an empty string is passed.

That is why when you need to emulate the behavior observed in .NET `Regex.Matches`, PHP `preg_match_all`, Python `re.finditer`, etc. you need to manually advance the index to test each position.

See [regex101.com test](https://regex101.com/r/hJ1gD9/1):

```js
var re = /a*/g; 
var str = 'dgwawa';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {   // <- this part
        re.lastIndex++;               // <- here
    }                                 // <- is important
    document.body.innerHTML += "'" + m[0] + "'<br/>";
}
```

If you remove that `if` block, you will get an infinite loop.

There are two very important things to mention with this regard:

- **Always use appropriate online regex tester for your programming language**
- **Avoid using unanchored patterns that can match empty strings**

Comment: Nice. I was told before regexr follows a specific regex flavor. I should take this into account more seriously.

Comment: See [*Online sandboxes (for testing and publishing regexes online)*](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) section to select the one that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer ans insights! Excellent job.

Comment: Just for the record, there is only one sandbox for .NET regex testing, and, compared to regexr, it is incomparably worse. So I rather stick using regexr with the highest awareness in mind :)

Comment: For testing .NET apps, you can use [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) and [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester). And if you need a functionality like regex101.com for .NET, use a very nice free app called [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 7 matches

Let me enumerate them, first number is the start (0 based), second number is the length

```
Match 1:             0       0   
Match 2:             1       0   
Match 3:             2       0   
Match 4:    a        3       1   
Match 5:             4       0   
Match 6:    a        5       1   
Match 7:             6       0
```

I use regex101 and it does what most of us expect from this simple regex (given there are regex dialects).

https://regex101.com/r/mN4jA4/1

Comment: I would be happy if the site reported 7, my problem is that is reports "infinite" matches ?! I would think like you, but I am afraid the mechanism does not work like that.