# Using exec to find multiple matches JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, exec

I'm having trouble interpreting the following code from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

```
var myRe = /ab*/g;
var str = 'abbcdefabh';
var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) { //confused by this line
  var msg = 'Found ' + myArray[0] + '. ';
  msg += 'Next match starts at ' + myRe.lastIndex;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

I'm confused by the while loop line. It seems to set myArray to the result of calling exec on the string str and says to continue if its not equal to null.

What I don't get is how the program knows to start searching from the last index where a match was found. To me it looks like this should be an infinite loop b/c I can't see where it says to start searching from the next index in an array.

Also, is there any reason to use exec to find multiple matches rather than just using match? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 1):

The `lastIndex` value is modified by the regex engine *internally* once you pass a regex *with a global modifier* to the `RegExp#exec`.

> If your regular expression uses the `"g"` flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property (`test()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).

Also, see [*15.10.6.2 `RegExp.prototype.exec(string)`*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) for the exact `RegExp#exec` specs. Especially:

> 11. If *global* is **true**,
>          a. Call the [[Put]] internal method of *R* with arguments "**lastIndex**", *e*, and **true**.

An infinite loop cannot occur since the pattern does not match an unancored empty string. It is `var myRe = /ab*/g;`, so `a` is oligatory in the input to return a valid match. If it were `var myRe = /a*/g;`, then there would be an infinite loop.

Also, check the [*Zero-Length regexes and infinite matches?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34495840/3832970) thread.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't get is how the program knows to start searching from the last index

In your regexp `myRe` there is a property `.lastIndex` that tells where `.exec` should start parsing.

`.exec` is useful when you want to parse a string piece by piece instead of all in once.

For more information on how `.exec` works, you can take a look at [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description).