# Regex with capture group not working, but without capture group works perfectly fine

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have the following string:

```
var str1 = "62y^2";
```

and I want the following result:

```
[62,y,^2]
```

Now when I tried the below regex I didn't get the desired result:

```
str.match(/(\d*)|([a-zA-Z]*)|(\^[a-zA-Z\d]*)/g)
```

But when I try the below regex:

```
str.match(/\^(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)|[a-zA-Z]+|\d+/g);
```

I get the desired result, why is my first regex not working? Is it because of the capture groups? I am not so well versed in regexs.

Comment: You did not use `g` modifier with the first regex, so you only got the first match.

Comment: Furthermore, you use `*` as quantifier in one and `+` in the other.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew even with the g modifier i dont' get the desired result I.E. `[62,y,^2]`

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik You did not move the regex lastIndex then. If you did, it would work even with `*`. Surely, `+` is what you need to match 1+ occurrences.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes you are right with the `+` operator , works fine. But why with `*` , i don't get the same result

Comment: See the dupe reason - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575281/regex-plus-vs-star-difference: `+` = 1 or more, `*` = 0 or more. When the regex with `g` modifier can match an empty string, the lastIndex is not updated and you have an infinite loop.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i still don't get it `str.match(/(\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)|(\^[a-zA-Z\d]+)/g)` works , but `str.match(/(\d*)|([a-zA-Z]*)|(\^[a-zA-Z\d]*)/g)` .... the only difference being .. i have changed the `+` to `*`. I have checked the dup question , but it does't really say anything about lastIndex being updated ....

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `So basically, if you use a + there must be at least one instance of the pattern, if you use * it will still match if there are no instances of it.` ... thats what your talking about i believe , i think i kind of get it !

Comment: See also [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495675/zero-length-regexes-and-infinite-matches/34495840#34495840) to see how to manually move lastIndex.