# How to find indexes of all non-matching characters with a JS regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, string-operations

I've got a string and I want to get an array with the indexes (positions) of the characters in this string that do not match a certain regex criteria.

The issue here is that if I write it like this:

```
let match;
let reg = /[A-Za-z]|[0-9]/g;
let str = "1111-253-asdasdas";
let indexes = [];

do {
    match = reg.exec(str);
    if (match) indexes.push(match.index);
} while (match);
```

It works. It returns the indexes of all the characters that are numerical or alphabetical. But the problem is that if I try to make the opposite, with a negative lookahead in Regex, like this:

```
let match;
let reg = /(?!([A-Za-z]|[0-9]))/g;
let str = "1111-253-asdasdas";
let indexes = [];

do {
    match = reg.exec(str);
    if (match) indexes.push(match.index);
} while (match);
```

It ends up in an infinite loop.

What I'd like to achieve is the same result as in the first case, but with the negative regex, so in this case the result would be:

```
indexes = [4, 8]; // which are the indexes in which a non-alphanumerical character appears
```

Is the loop wrong, or it's the regex expression the one who is messing things up? Maybe the `exec` is not working with negative lookaheads Regex expressions?

I would understand the regex expression not working as I intended to (because it may be wrongly formatted), but I don't understand the infinite loop, which leads me to think that `exec` maybe is not the best way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: The infinite loop is easy to explain: the regex has a `g` modifier and thus tries to match multiple occurrences of the pattern, but since your pattern matches an empty string, and you do not check the condition if the `index` is equal to `lastIndex`, the regex cannot advance in  a string. Use a regex to match any non-alphanumeric chars, `/[\W_]/g`

Comment: cant' you just change the regex so that it searches for non-alphanumeric characters: `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for the explanation, as this was the reason of my question, because I did not understand why this was happening.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thank you because that's exactly what I was trying to achieve!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I reopened because your duplicate link was not specific enough.

Comment: Sorry @WiktorStribiżew, can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? It explains why the `exec` ends in an infinite loop, and furthermore brings a working answer for my case, which solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Unapedra Yes, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason**

The infinite loop is easy to explain: the regex has a `g` modifier and thus tries to match multiple occurrences of the pattern starting each matching attempt after the end of the previous successful match, that is, after the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) value:

See [`exec` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> If your regular expression uses the "`g`" flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property

However, since your pattern matches an empty string, and you do not check the condition if the index is equal to `lastIndex`, the regex cannot advance in a string.

**Solution**

Use a regex to match any non-alphanumeric chars, `/[\W_]/g`. Since it does not match empty strings the `lastIndex` property of the RegExp object will be changed with each match and no infinite loop will occur.

**JS demo:**

```js
let match, indexes = [];
let reg = /[\W_]/g;
let str = "1111-253-asdasdas";

while (match = reg.exec(str)) {
    indexes.push(match.index);
}
console.log(indexes);
```

Also, see [how to move the `lastIndex` property value manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34495840/3832970).

Answer (score 3):

This approach replaces all matching characters with a star `*`.  Then, we iterate that replaced string and retrieve all indices which do *not* match the regex character class.

```js
var str = "1111-253-asdasdas";
var pattern = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g;
str = str.replace(pattern, "*");

var indices = [];
for(var i=0; i < str.length;i++) {
    if (str[i] === "*") indices.push(i);
}
console.log(indices.toString());
```

In this case, only characters at positions 4 and 8 do not match, because they are underscores.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you mean dashes/hyphens, not underscores?